# Stuck with selecting distinct records with sum

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry guys, I tried, but I had to ask. I wasn't going anywhere with this.

```
Here's my table `likes`:
"id"    "type"  "parent" "country" "votes"
"1"          "1"    "0" "US"    NULL
"2"          "2"    "1" "US"    NULL
"3"          "3"    "2" "US"    NULL
"4"          "10"   "3" "US"    "5"
"5"          "10"   "3" "US"    "15"
"6"          "10"   "3" "US"    "25"
"7"          "3"    "2" "US"    NULL
"8"          "10"   "7" "US"    "40"
"9"          "10"   "7" "US"    "25"
"10"     "10"   "7" "US"    "60"
"19"     "3"    "1" "US"    NULL
"20"     "10"   "19"    "US"    "10"
"21"     "10"   "19"    "US"    "20"
"22"     "10"   "19"    "US"    "30"
```

From this, I'm trying to `select distinct parent , sum votes where type = 10 and country = 'us'`

I tried this: `SELECT SUM(likes.votes) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT parent, votes FROM likes where type = 10) likes;` but I end up with pretty odd results.

How can I do this?

The result I'm trying to get is this:

```
parent | total
3      | 45
7      | 125
9      | 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT parent,sum(votes) as total FROM `likes` 
WHERE type = 10 GROUP BY parent ORDER BY parent ASC
```

Comment: @Gautham3164 yes it is . Thanks. Pls wait a sec.

Answer (score 1):

check [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04c8c/8)

```
select distinct parent, sum(votes) from likes 
where type = 10 and country = 'us' GROUP BY parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select parent, sum(votes) ...
group by parent
```

??

Comment: Egads! Who would have thunk it was this simple?